# Generating MapService tiles cache from machine other than server with ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, tiles, map-service

I have a MapService published on ArcGIS Server v10.3. I would like to generate the tiles cache for this service. For an unknown reason ArcGIS Server CPUs are getting overloaded to 99%-100% after a few day of processing.

When that happen, all the other services published to ArcGIS Server are not responding very well until I kill the tool that generate the tiles. Then, I can restart the tool and continue to generate the tiles for another few days before the CPUs get overloaded again.

I would like to know if there is a way to generate the tiles for a MapService from another machine, like a virtual machine with an ArcGIS Desktop license and a writing access to the server drive disk.

The generate time is not really important. I would like to prevent the tiles generation process to have a negative impact on all the services.

Comment: Yes and No.  Yes, a different computer can generate tiles, but it has to have the same (or substantially similar) configuration as the original server. I question whether a "personal computer" is going to hold up under the load that crippled a server class machine.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to reflect this information. Unfortunately, there really isn't anything wrong with tile processing running for several days.  With some large installations, it might take compute-months to rebuild a cache.  Using another VM in the same enclosure may not improve matters if the load isn't managed carefully.  It's possible that your original server is under-provisioned.

Comment: It's possible for a Server install to build a cache offline. I would not recommend writing to shared disk. Far better to write to independent disk, then copy over the cache after is is finished (this is done all the time).

Comment: It seems that ArcGIS Desktop can generate tiles using the [Manage Tile Cache](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/manage-tile-cache.htm) tool

Answer (score 2):

It seems that ArcGIS Desktop/Pro can generate tiles using the [Manage Tile Cache](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/manage-tile-cache.htm) tool which:

> Creates a tile cache or updates tiles in an existing tile cache. You
>   can use this tool to create new tiles, replace missing tiles,
>   overwrite outdated tiles, and delete tiles.